# brew mysqld not starting

Tags: mysql, homebrew, macos-mojave

Mac OSX Mojave. I have `mysql@5.6` installed with `brew`. I have run `brew link --force mysql@5.6`.

```
$ cat /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.6.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.6</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I run `/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin/mysqld_safe` from the terminal directly, `mysqld` starts. If I try running `brew services restart mysql@5.6`, it does not (but brew says it does - but it appears yellow in `brew services list`).

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with brew nginx package.
Running it with `sudo` worked for me.

Try running:

`sudo brew services restart mysql@5.6`